# Help with SQL Query Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to the following

```
ID NUMBER
VAL1 NUMBER
VAL2 NUMBER
```

I need an SQL query that displays count of rows that have VAL1 > VAL2 and Count of rows that have VAL1 < VAL2. Both counts using one SQL query. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should work with most database platforms:

```
 select sum(case when val1 > val2 then 1 end) as GreaterThanCount,
    sum(case when val1 < val2 then 1 end) as LessThanCount
from MyTable
```

To show the sums in separate rows, you can do:

```
select case when val1 > val2 then 'GreaterThan' else 'LessThan' end as Type,
    count(*) as Count
from MyTable    
group by case when val1 > val2 then 'GreaterThan' else 'LessThan' end
```

Comment: Is it possible to display the counts in two different rows with the same SQL query?

Comment: Note that rows where val1 = val2 are caught in the "LessThan" bucket here.

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT SUM(VAL1 > VAL2) as arg1,
>   SUM(VAL1 < VAL2) as arg2

Comment: Is it possible to display the counts in two different rows with the same SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, count(VAL1 > VAL2) as more1, count(val2 > val1) as more2
from your_table
```

Comment: Is it possible to display the counts in two different rows with the same SQL query?